# unable to change wordpress upload dir to root of the website

Tags: wordpress

is there a way to change the uploads folder to one outside the wordpress installation folder?

i have made some changes in wp-config file like

```
define( 'UPLOADS', "http://www.domain.com/media/uploads" );
```

from:
http://www.domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads

to:
http://www.domain.com/media/uploads

default:

```
domain
-wordpress
--wp-content
---uploads 

I need:
domain
-media
--uploads
-wordpress
```

Comment: $p."/'http'://www.domain.com/media/uploads"     is not a path.. try echo'ing it out to see what you are actually defining.

Comment: are you able to solve this problem ?? dont give any negative point if you are not able to solve it

Comment: i've just told you how to solve it....

Comment: if you kind of people dont know anything about problem then why are you giving negative marking??? if you have really knowledge about this problem then prove it by solve this problem. here no one have the answer about this problem and you are marking it Negative why???????

Comment: i know exactly what the problem is, i told you the issue, its not a negative thing, its exactly what is wrong. But you seem to have some kind of attitude, i do not benefit by helping you but yet you see fit to launch a tirade of abuse. So on that note good luck solving it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', '../media/uploads' );
```

There is also a plugin to define the media path: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-original-media-path/

For old version:
Settings -> Miscellaneous -> Store uploads in this folder => '/../media/uploads' 
[Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/uploads-folder-outside-wp-root)

Comment: where to find "Miscellaneous"??? there is not option like Miscellaneous in settings menu at admin side. actually i am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: Sorry on old Wordpress it was accessible.
Did you try: `define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'medias/uploads' );` ?

Comment: And with `define( 'UPLOADS', '../media/uploads' );` ? You can have rights issues with your server

Comment: What show this ? Because wordpress can find the path and he can be able to upload the files to this folder.
And can you give your wordpress version ?

Comment: WordPress 4.2.4  also not working in latest version WordPress 4.3

Comment: Ok, now what show this ? Did you try to add a media file ? What wordpress said ?

Comment: http://domain.com/wordpress/../media/uploads     file is uploaded successfully but different location here :  domain.com/wordpress/../media/uploads

Comment: Ok but when you go into your media/uploads folder there is the file uploaded ?
When you try to insert a media inside some article does it works ?

Comment: yes file is uploaded and displays also on that path